# Combine the store details according to pincode

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection "test", contains store data. Two of documents are show below-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfffd884c90a040bab5e35a"),
    "facilityCode" : "ST99",
    "area" : "Bokaro",
    "landmark" : "Vivira Mall",
    "storeContact" : NumberLong(06542233443),
    "pinCode" : 827004,
    "Status" : "Active"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfffd884c90a040bab5e35b"),
    "facilityCode" : "ST100",
    "area" : "Bokaro",
    "landmark" : "Opera Mall",
    "storeContact" : NumberLong(9909090909),
    "pinCode" : 827004,
    "Status" : "InActive"
}
```

There may be multiple stores at a perticuar pincode(one to many relationship). I want all the stores at a perticular pincode to be in one document, like bolow -

```
{
    "pincode" : 827004,
    "storeDetail" : [ 
        {
            "landmark" : "Vivira Mall",
            "facilityCode" : "ST99",
            "area" : "Bokaro",
            "storeContact" : "06542233443",
            "priority" : 0,
            "Status" : "Active"
        },
        {
            "landmark" : "Opera Mall",
            "facilityCode" : "ST100",
            "area" : "Bokaro",
            "storeContact" : "9909090909",
            "priority" : 0,
            "Status" : "InActive"
        }
    ]
}
```

Priority can set to zero for all. Thanks

Comment: You should put some effort to at least have your sample data in a text/code form so we can copy/paste it and give you better answer. If I have the answer for you in an image form you probably would not appreciate it very much. Also it does not seem like you have made an attempt to solve this yourself ... if you have post what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate and group them like this:

```
Collection.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: '$pinCode'}, storeDetail: {
    $push: {
        landmark: '$landmark',
        facilityCode: '$facilityCode',
        area: '$area',
        storeContact: '$storeContact',
        priority: 0,
        Status: '$Status'
    }
}},
{$project: {pincode: '$_id', storeDetail: 1}}
```

])